# How would the host share a workspace with docker container in the development workflow?

Tags: node.js, intellij-idea, docker

I know that I can mount a folder from the host machine to the container. However, if I develop on Mac, the application may require a different dependecy to run in the container. What is the recommended practice to share this folder across host and container.

Example:

We have a nodejs project:

```
workspace
  |\-node_modoule
  |\-app
  |\-config
  ....
```

The host maching is running **Mac OSX** and the container is running **Ubuntu**. When I try to debug the projec in IDE (Intellij idea for example), I should have all dependencies in node_modoule folder which could be **OS specific**. Then when I run it with container would fail, because it might require difference dependencies.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `node_modules/` to `.dockerignore` to prevent sucking this directory into context and then share each directory via standard `volume` command.
E.g. compose file:

```
web:
  build: .
  volumes:
  # need to list all directories due to node_modules/ and bower_components/ :/
    - "app:/src/app"
    - "client:/src/client"
    - "config:/src/config"
    - "public:/src/public"
    - "scripts:/src/scripts"

  links:
    - "redis:redis"
  ports:
    - "8888:8888"
  command: node_modules/.bin/grunt

  redis:
    image: redis
```